# Increment a column based on its id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Im making a drag n drop sortable list. What I am trying to do is increment a column in **MySql** based on its id value automatically when new records are entered. ie:

- if i have a row with an id = 3, and it is the first record enetered
  for that id, then its recordid = 1.
- if i have a row with an id = 14, and it is the first record enetered
  for that id, then its recordid = 1.
- if i have a row with an id = 3, and it is the second record enetered
  for that id, then its recordid = 2.

So i want it to autoincrement recordid based on its id value. not the whole table value. Does that make sence? what code would i need in php to find the highest value recordid pertaining to the id and then increment it by 1 when a new record is entered? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `recordid`) VALUES
(
    $id,
    (SELECT MAX(`recordid`) + 1 AS `rid` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = $id)
);
```

You could probably optimize it way further though.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could nest a query inside a query. =) Ill give this a go. Cheers.

Comment: ok so i have: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO userlinks (id,hash,url,title,posid)
    VALUES (
     '".$_SESSION['id']."',
     '".md5($_GET['url'])."',
     '".$_GET['url']."',
     '".$_GET['title']."',
     (SELECT MAX (posid) + 1 AS rid FROM userlinks WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."')
    )");` Does not seem to be working. Any suggestions?